# Matrix ignores position or rotation

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview, android-canvas

Im drawing a bitmap at a canvas. Im trying to have this bitmap rotate and change position.

For that im using this code:

```
 matrix.setTranslate(pos_x, 15);
 matrix.setRotate(30);
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix,paint);
```

And all this is in a loop so the variable "pos_x" will be increased.

But it seems like matrix wont accept both of these lines, setTranslate and setRotate.
The bitmap is rotated when i comment out the setTranslate. And the bitmap is moving when i comment out the rotate. But they won't work together!

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is in the meaning of the word 'set'.

Instead of setting aka overwriting the matrix, one should incrementally adjust it: 
either should one first setTranslate and then Rotate, or setRotate and then Translate.

Comment: If the library doesn't have functions without the prefix "set", then one can have `matrixA.setRotate(); matrixB.setTranslate();` and multiply these for the intended result.

Comment: There are methods for this ``Matrix.preRotate`` and/or ``Matrix.postRotate``.

Comment: how do I multiply two matrixes?

Comment: @user1469324 you don't have to. You can use ``Matrix.preRotate`` or ``Matrix.postRotate`` methods to concat rotation into existing matrix. Multiplying happens using ``Matrix.preConcat`` or ``Matrix.postConcat`` though.

Answer (score 1):

For futur Googlers,

The matrix commands beginning by setXXX will always reset the matrix. So if you send a setRotate and then a setTranslate, the setRotate will be reset and won't apply.

Luckily, you have to other sets of commands : the preXXX and the postXXX

So you can do preRotate and then setTranslate to achieve what you want to do.

You could even :

```
matrix.preRotate(90);
matrix.setTranslate(120,120);
matrix.postScale(2.0f);
```